# Link-Only Answer Flag Declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently flagged the following answer as "Low-Quality" [NSDate is older than today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180608/nsdate-is-older-than-today/30180631#30180631) but was declined by a moderator via "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

I've gotten my hand smacked before for flagging link-only answers using "in need of moderator intervention" and adding comments but was told to flag it as "VLQ".

First question: why isn't there a Link-only Answer choice out of the main pool of flags? What is the course of action when a LOA is given but a moderator thinks it can be salvaged by the answerer adding more details?

Second Question: Looking through Meta I see this question is posed a lot with seemingly the same course of direction so why is there such a vast gap in moderators enforcing it? While moderation is often opinion I somewhat see LOA's as pretty black and white.

Comment: I really do not get why this would have been declined. It *is* a link-only answer.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why I declined it. It was a mistake and it's now been deleted. I probably read that as "use this..." thinking it was a function, etc not a library. My mistake.

Comment: @bluefeet No worries. I just didn't understand from the bigger picture perspective why that would have been declined. Go have another drink ;)

Comment: Oh @Dan it's not even 8am yet, too early for drinks. That will be later. ;P

Comment: Well if you declined that flag I figured you were one of those all day drinkers is all. Obviously kidding.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First answer: because links aren't the problem. Not attempting to answer the question is the problem.

Second answer: moderators are human, and humans make mistakes. Hundreds of these flags are raised every day; most of them are acted on and marked helpful, but some small % are judged invalid. A large portion of them are handled by the community at large via /review - those have roughly a 12% error rate. I personally handle a small portion of them, with about a 9% error rate. Various moderators handle a greater or lesser portion, with error rates ranging from about 1% to 13%.

The vast majority of the time, flags are handled correctly. If a flag of yours is declined, you should always take a second look & see if perhaps there's something you missed, a different way in which you could've handled the situation... But if you feel strongly, re-flag the post and explain the problem (as you did in this case) - it will be re-reviewed and any errors corrected.

Comment: I appreciate the commentary and agree with all of it, especially the re-review of your own declined flags. I specifically asked the question from an inquisitive standpoint (as opposed to accusatory) simply because I felt that it was perhaps a slight miss. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not hindering the community with errant flags.

Comment: You've had 10 flags declined in your entire history here, @Zero - under 3% of the flags you've raised. The last declined flag was [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843927/do-variables-defined-inside-list-comprehensions-leak-into-the-enclosing-scope/29847246#29847246), which... Ok, it's a pretty crappy answer, but arguably the author could be trying to demonstrate a less error-prone method of writing the logic. Expecting moderators to judge the helpfulness or technical accuracy of such answers isn't realistic; just downvote unless it's *clearly* not intended to answer.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Or maybe Shog just went through and hid them from you to make you question your memory/sanity. :)