Should I re-flag a declined "Not An Answer" flag on a link-only answer?
I flagged the following answer as "not an answer" because the actual answer is in the link inside the answer. This flag was declined, should I re-flag it?
Answer:

I found this which is a very small snippet that uses the WebUSB
API and lets you print some text with a USB-attached printer, so I
guess there's the solution. You'll just have to format your own string
and feed it to the encoder, but in the end it should work.
If you see an error like "Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied." follow this and it'll work.


This is, probably, one of those times where this is an "answer" in there if you remove the noise: "[Use a] WebUSB API [that] lets you print some text with a USB-attached printer. You'll just have to format your own string and feed it to the encoder."

@ThomA you typed the answer in the comment box ...

@Cuzy My intention flagging this was exactly that, why not add the snippet to the answer? Its just bad UX not to. Also, answers with links to the answer are considered not an answer.

answers with links to the answer are considered not an answer.  No, that is not what we consider to be not an answer on the link-only definition. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer

Relevant Shog9 wisdom: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294407 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311969

It really helps to translate NAA to "Not an Attempt to Answer". Calling it "Not An Answer" is just one of Stack Overflow's many wonderful ways to make it as ambiguous and conflicting as possible. Everyone makes up their own laundry list of rules when an answer is an answer. This is a pretty poor attempt to answer, plain and simple.

I wonder about the odds of you discovering and acting upon an actual link-only answer before ol' smokey.

Stephen Ostermiller's answer addresses why this specific flag was declined.
In the general case, where you have read over the guidelines for what qualifies as "Not an answer" and still believe that the handling moderator made a mistake:
Yes, you should raise an "In need of moderator intervention" flag and provide an explanation for why you believe the flag should be accepted, such as:

This is a link-only answer (NAA flag previously declined). Simply pointing the user to the WebUSB API as a whole (which has use-cases nearly as broad as the range of devices you can plug into USB ports), with absolutely no hint as to even what part of the API to use, is not an answer.  All actual content is behind the link.

Note: This example flag text is intended as an example of how to explain the thinking behind one's NAA flag, rather than a statement of what should or should not be flagged as NAA.
The reason for providing the explanation is that if the flag was declined and the post was left up, that suggests that the handling moderator didn't understand why it was being flagged that way.

Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer? has the canonical instructions for evaluating whether or not an answer is link-only: "Strip the markup."   That is, if the links were removed, is there information left that could answer the question, even partially or minimally? If so, the answer is more than a link.
As the moderator that handled the flag, I agree with Thom A's comment.

This is, probably, one of those times where this is an "answer" in there if you remove the noise: "[Use a] WebUSB API [that] lets you print some text with a USB-attached printer. You'll just have to format your own string and feed it to the encoder."

If you take out the links, it is still an attempt to answer.  It has enough information to at least point in the right direction.  If the links break, this answer could still be minimally helpful. This answer is low quality, but it would still count as an answer.  Such low quality answers can be voted down, but they should be not be flagged.

The quote you show is not an answer, it is just some handwaving which suggests there is an answer, without providing an actual answer. For that you really need to follow the link.

@StephenOstermiller If the bar for being an answer (even if a bad one) is that it essentially says "I think this question is answerable" then I guess I'll need to reevaluate a LOT of my flagging... At least Fermat would be proud I guess

This looks like more than "this should be answerable" to me.  It has four specific things that you need to do:  1 Use WebUSB API 2. Connect the printer with USB 3. Format your string 4. Feed it to the encoder.  Yes it is missing important details about how to do those things, but to me it looks like a minimal attempt to answer the question.  If the answer were literally "I think this question is answerable" that is clearly not-an-answer.
